# input_fn optimisation for tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am building a TensorFlow Estimator that I want to train and evaluate using the `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()` function. The [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) for this function gives the following advice:

> It is also recommended to train the model a little longer, say multiple epochs, before performing evaluation, as the input pipeline starts from scratch for each training.

This makes sense, as `train_and_evaluate()` works by alternating between calling `estimator.train()` and `estimator.evaluate()`, tearing down the computational graph for each new call. In my case this is a problem, as I want to evaluate the model relatively often, and my `input_fn` seems to have a lot of overhead in setup. It currently looks something like this:

```
def input_fn():
    # Build dataset from generator
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=instance_generator,
        output_types=types,
        output_shapes=shapes,
    )

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs_per_eval)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

    return dataset
```

I suspect a lot of the time cost in this function comes from the shuffling, since it requires generating the entire dataset first. The shuffling probably isn't slow, but my `instance_generator` is. Ideally I would like to find a way of avoiding having to rebuild the dataset from a generator for each train/eval call. Is there any way I can achieve this using the Dataset class? Is there a way I can cache the state of dataset after it has been generated, so that every new call to `input_fn` after the first gets less expensive?

Comment: You should not cache anything tensorflow-related outside the input_fn as Estimator creates a fresh graph each time. Is your bottleneck in the building of the input_fn (unlikely) or execution of it?

Also, why are you shuffling during eval?

Comment: I know Estimator creates a new graph every time. What I was hoping was that you could maintain a separate graph outside the estimator that you plug in to the estimator's graph as it is built. The bottleneck is getting the first batch of data returned; after that it works fine. I'm also not shuffling during eval. The problem is that every eval triggers the rebuilding of the *training* input pipeline, which is, and should be, shuffled.

Comment: It still sounds like you want to cache a value and not a graph. I don't think this is supported now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use tf.data.Dataset.range other than tf.data.Dataset.from_generator. Here is the sample code:
First, define Python class

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

class instance_generator():
    def __init__(self):
        #doing some initialization
        self.data_index = {n:str(n) for n in range(1000)}# create index othre than pretreat data

    def _hard_work(self, n):
        time.sleep(1) #doing the pretreating work
        return self.data_index[n]

    def __call__(self):
        def get_by_index(i):
            return tf.py_func(lambda i: self._hard_work(i), inp=[i], Tout=types)

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(len(self.data_index))
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset_size)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs_per_eval)
        dataset = dataset.map(get_by_index)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
        return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().next()
```

Then, feed instance_generator class to tf.estimator:

```
data_train = instance_generator('train')
data_eval = instance_generator('eval')
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    estimator=model,
    train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(data_train),
    eval_spec=tf.estimator.Estimator(data_eval)
)
```

If the initialization step is time consuming, it runs ony onece, whenever estimator creates a new graph, it ony creats dataset. 
If data pretreating is time consuming, it works only on the feeding batch of data, but not the whole dataset. Shuffle and repeat on index is quite cheap.
Hope it helps.